# How to get total read and total write IOPS in Linux?

Tags: linux, io, disk, read, write

How do I get read and write IOPS separately in Linux, using command line or in a programmatic way? I have installed `sysstat` package.

Please tell me how do I calculate these separately using `sysstat` package commands.

Or, is it possible to calculate them using file system?

**ex:** `/proc` or `/sys` or `/dev`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`iostat` is part of the `sysstat` package, which is able to show overall iops if desired, or show them separated by reads/writes.

Run `iostat` with the -d flag to only show the device information page, and -x for detailed information (separate read/write stats).  You can specify the device you want information for by simply adding it afterwards on the command line.

Try running `iostat -dx` and looking at the summary to get a feel for the output.  You can also use `iostat -dx 1` to show a continuously refreshing output, which is useful for troubleshooting or live monitoring,

Using `awk`, field 4 will give you *reads/second*, while field 5 will give you *writes/second*.

Reads/second only:

`iostat -dx <your disk name> | grep <your disk name> | awk '{ print $4; }'`

Writes/sec only:

`iostat -dx <your disk name> | grep <your disk name> | awk '{ print $5; }'`

Reads/sec and writes/sec separated with a slash:

`iostat -dx <your disk name> | grep <your disk name> | awk '{ print $4"/"$5; }'`

Overall IOPS (what most people talk about):

`iostat -d <your disk name> | grep <your disk name> | awk '{ print $2; }'`

For example, running the last command with my main drive, /dev/sda, looks like this:

`dan@daneel ~ $ iostat -dx sda | grep sda | awk '{ print $4"/"$5; }'
15.59/2.70`

Note that you do *not* need to be root to run this either, making it useful for non-privileged users.

TL;DR: If you're just interested in `sda`, the following command will give you overall IOPS for `sda`:

`iostat -d sda | grep sda | awk '{ print $2; }'`

If you want to add up the IOPS across **all** devices, you can use awk again:

`iostat -d | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'`

This produces output like so:

`dan@daneel ~ $ iostat -d | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'
18.88`

Comment: Thanks Mr.Dannel its useful. if i want to get full system Read/Write IOPS How to get ?

Comment: when i run `iostat -dx 1` i got ans like this `Linux 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.i686 (shashi)  08/24/2015  _i686_ (2 CPU)

Device:   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  r/s  w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda      2.46 13.80 2.27 2.03   136.26   123.91 60.53  0.11   25.77   4.43   1.91
dm-0     0.00  0.00 2.35 0.77 93.07  6.11 31.86  0.17   53.73   2.59   0.81
dm-1     0.00  0.00 1.02 2.83  8.14 22.66  8.00  0.83  214.34   0.60   0.23
dm-2     0.00  0.00 1.37   11.89 34.77 95.14  9.80  1.67  126.06   0.84   1.11`
for dm-0,dm-1,dm-2 recursively should i add?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an overall template and an example for `sda`.  If you simply want to see the IOPS for your hard drive, then use that last command for overall IOPS (`iostat -d sda | grep sda | awk '{ print $2; }'`)

Comment: No i want separately as u mention in 1st answer. bit confuse with `dm-*` so i asked, i need to perform addition on those partitions

Comment: Ahh, ok.  You can use the following command to check what each `dm-x` device is: `lvdisplay|awk  '/LV Name/{n=$3} /Block device/{d=$3; sub(".*:","dm-",d); print d,n;}'` - I will update the answer with this, as well as how to add the results.

Comment: You can skip the grep and just use awk.  `iostat -d sda | grep sda | awk '{ print $2; }'` becomes `iostat -d sda | awk '$1=="sda"{ print $2; }'` or `iostat -d sda | awk '/sda/{ print $2; }'`.  The performance overhead is minimal, but I'm a big fan of flattening grep|awk in general. :)

Comment: Shouldn't we sum up `Blk_read/s` and `Blk_wrtn/s` instead of `tps` column to get IOPS?

Comment: Useful for monitoring IOPS (for `sda`): `iostat -d 1 sda | grep --line-buffered sda | awk -W interactive '{ print $2; }'`

Comment: Is this the output of IOPS I'm doing right now, or the maximum for my disks?